# Grouping results in SOLR?

Tags: solr

I have a Solr index with a schema that looks like this:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "q.op": "OR",
      "_": "1673422604341"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1206,
    "start": 0,
    "numFoundExact": true,
    "docs": [
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName1",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName1",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 1.11,
        "received_date_dt": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName1",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName2",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 2.22,
        "received_date_dt": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName1",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName3",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 3.33,
        "received_date_dt": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName2",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName1",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 4.44,
        "received_date_dt": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName2",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName2",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 5.55,
        "received_date_dt": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName2",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName3",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 6.66,
        "received_date_dt": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

These are historical prices for different materials from different companies.

I would like to get the lowest `price_per_lb_value_f` for each `material_name_s` in last 2 years, so the results would look like this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "numFoundExact": true,
    "docs": [
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName1",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName3",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 3.33,
        "received_date_dt": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "material_name_s":"MaterialName2",
        "company_name_s": "CompanyName2",
        "price_per_lb_value_f": 5.55,
        "received_date_dt": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this kind of grouping is even possible to do with Solr?
I'm a newbie to Solr, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the JSON Facet API: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html ? It allows you to use aggregate functions for each bucket.

Comment: Yes, but there is a problem. I can get a list of material names with their lowest price, but I don't know how to add a company_name and received_date for that particular price to be included in the result.

Comment: That would be the terms that you facet against (i.e. the keys you want to group by). You'd facet against material_name_s to retrieve the lowest value for each material name. You can then perform a search against these two values if you want to retrieve the content (or add another level in your facet and limit it to the top hit, possibly?)

Answer (score 1):

grouping is possible in Solr.
You can get the result you want with the following queries:

1. **Field collapsing approach (recommended in your case)**:
   https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/collapse-and-expand-results.html

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=received_date_dt:[NOW-3YEAR%20TO%20*]&fq={!collapse%20field=material_name_s%20min=price_per_lb_value_f}
```

`q:received_date_dt:[NOW-3YEAR TO *]`    // Range query to filter only the documents received in the last 3 years otherwise I wouldn't get documents received on 2021-01-01
`fq:{!collapse field=material_name_s min=price_per_lb_value_f}`  // It shows only one document within all documents with the same value of `material_name_s`. It gets the document with the min `price_per_lb_value_f`

2. **Grouping approach**: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/result-grouping.html

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=received_date_dt:[NOW-3YEAR%20TO%20*]&group=true&group.field=material_name_s&group.sort=price_per_lb_value_f%20asc
```

`q:received_date_dt:[NOW-3YEAR TO *]`  // same filter as before
`group:true`  // enable grouping
`group.field:material_name_s`  // groups by `material_name_s`
`group.sort:price_per_lb_value_f asc`  // sort each group by the field `price_per_lb_value_f` in ascending order
`group.limit` not specified as the default value is 1  // it sets the number of results for each group